# CSS3 background-image slider: animate and background-size

Tags: image, google-chrome, css, slider

I am creating an image-slider by using CSS only. I am almost done coding, but I can't figure out what I have to do so that the images don't scale unproportional while sliding.  I still want them to fill the div and not to be stretched at 100% and I also don't want to cut the images because I want (you) to figure out a way to do this :)

Here's a part of my code:

```
div#transition3 {
  width:480px; 
  height:360px; 
  -webkit-animation:trans2 12s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
  -webkit-background-origin:border-box; 
  background-scale:fill; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes trans2 /* Safari and Chrome */
{
  0%   {background:url('../img/1.jpg') no-repeat top left;}
  10%  {background:url('../img/1.jpg') no-repeat top left;}
  20%  {background:url('../img/2.jpg') no-repeat top left;}
  30%  {background:url('../img/2.jpg') no-repeat top left;}
  40%  {background:url('../img/3.jpg') no-repeat top left;}
  50%  {background:url('../img/3.jpg') no-repeat top left;}
  60%  {background:url('../img/4.jpg') no-repeat top left;}
  70%  {background:url('../img/4.jpg') no-repeat top left;}
  80%  {background:url('../img/5.jpg') no-repeat top left;}
  90%  {background:url('../img/5.jpg') no-repeat top left;}
  100% {background:url('../img/1.jpg') no-repeat top left;}
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qDmS8/3/.
I hope you know what I mean and be able to help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: isnt it `background-size:cover`? not `background-scale:fill`? ive never seen that before.

Comment: Use `cover` instead of `fill`: http://jsfiddle.net/qDmS8/4/

Comment: You were both right. It's background-size:fill.
But take a look at it now. It behaves buggy. Also I don't want the first image to transform into the next. It should fade without transforming.
http://jsfiddle.net/qDmS8/16/

Comment: sry, I meant background-size:cover!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do it the way I wanted to.
The best way to do this is to create containers for each image, then assign CSS transitions to them as seen on http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/index.html